# Smallest and largest constants in $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ norms equivalence relation.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

We know that $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ norms are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$; that is there exist constants $0<c_1\leq c_2$ such that
$$ c_1\|x\|_1\leq \|x\|_2 \leq c_2\|x\|_1 $$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
It is clear that we can take $c_2=1$ and, by using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, $c_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

My question is: are these two choices of $c_1$ and $c_2$ the largest and the smallest constants such that the inequality is satisfied? How can I find the largest $c_1$ and the smallest $c_2$?

Comment: One approach would be to find whether there are cases of equality in the two proofs you have.

Comment: Oh right! Suppose we pick a $c_1=k$ and there exists $x$ such that $k\|x\|_1=\|x\|_2$ holds, if $c_1 = k+\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon>0$, we have $c_1\|x\|_1>\|x\|_2$ which contradicts the inequality. This proves that $c_1=k$ is the largest.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@JamieRadcliffe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/25795/jamie-radcliffe) in the comment, suppose we let $c_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $c_2=1$ and if we show that there are non-zero $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|x_1\|_1=\|x_1\|_2$ and $\|x_2\|_2=\|x_2\|_1$, we essentially prove that such choices of $c_1$ and $c_2$ are indeed the largest and the smallest.

It turns out that this is true. We can choose $x_1=(\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n})$ and $x_2$ = $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and see that the equalities hold.